# why request.vars are added an additional key "records" with null value when I used the sqlform.grid?

Tags: web2py

My web2py version is 2.14.6.

I define a form in myview.html

```
   `<form action="{{=URL('default','sj_xxxx')}}" method='get'>
    <input id='shizhou' name='shizhou'>
    <input id='xianqu' name='xianqu'>
    <input id='xiangzhen' name='xiangzhen'>
    <input type="submit" value="query">
    </form>`
```

In my default controler function 'index' I want to deal with the request.vars passed from html.It works fine. Then I add a `form=SQLFORM.grid(query)` to my function, I find that the request.vars are added an additional key "records" with null value when the sqlform.grid() line is executed. So I debug into the source code, I find the line 2479 in sqlhtml.py is

`elif not request.vars.records:
     request.vars.records = []`

After the above line excuted my request.vars was added an additional key "records" with null value. My questions are,

1.How can I prevent adding the "record" key to my request.vars?

2.What's the purpose of the code

`elif not request.vars.records:
     request.vars.records = []`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The grid optionally includes a column of checkboxes to allow individual records to be selected, and when that is done, the IDs of the selected records are stored in `request.vars.records` (as well as `request.post_vars.records`, as the selections are submitted via a POST request).

You can remove the `records` key via the usual means:

```
del request.vars.records
```

or

```
request.vars.pop('records')
```

However, instead of doing that, you can access just the variables from your custom form via `request.get_vars`, as your form is submitted via a GET request.